# Impossible Geometry, I think that the case is not possible, but I might be wrong.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

**Question:**

In acute $\Delta ABC$, let $D$ be the foot of the altitude from $A$ to $BC$, and let $\overline{AD}$
intersect the circumcircle of $\Delta ABC$  at $E$.

Let the circle with diameter $AE$ intersect lines $AB$ and $AC$ at $N$ and $M$, respectively. Given that $DB=3NB$ and $MA=5NA$,

then the value of $\displaystyle \frac{DC}{MC} $ can be written in simplest form as $\displaystyle \frac{a}{b}$. What is the value of $a-b$?

[SOURCE](https://brilliant.org/problems/interesting-circles/)

**My attempt to draw:** Please guide me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: My idea is, it will never intersect AC and AB simultaneously because if we shift the perpendicular, then it'll be maximum in length when it is the diameter of circle $C(O,AO)$ then it will only touch B and C.

Comment: # Shifting perpendicular along with $A$.

Answer (score 3):

The problem statement says, "Let the circle with diameter $AE$ intersect **lines** $AB$ and $AC$" (emphasis added by me).

If the statement had said "**sides** $AB$ and $AC$" then your constructions would be counterexamples. But the **line** $AC$ is generally considered to be the line through $A$ and $C$ extended indefinitely in any direction. Since the circle with diameter $AE$ intersects that circle at $A$ and is not tangent to the line at $A$, it will certainly intersect the line at one other point. That point may not be between $A$ and $C$ but it will still exist.

Comment: This does seem the most likely interpretation, with the assumption that $M\neq N\neq A$

Comment: Yes, I agree with it :)

Comment: Let me retry the Question using this fact !

Comment: @lioness99a Yes, since $A$ is one of the intersections it might have been useful for the problem statement to explicitly rule out $M=A$ and $N=A.$ I think the following equations implicitly make those identities impossible, but a clear statement is better. For that matter, the problem could have said something like "(possibly extended) sides" rather than "lines". I don't think you have to be completely happy with the way the problem is worded.

Comment: @DavidK I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

It does indeed appear to indicate that there is a typo in the question as posed. The circle with the diameter $AE$ does not have to intersect $AB$ and $AC$ at all, and so in particular the point $M$ does not exist.